# When do we need socket and when do we need request?

Tags: python, socket.io, request

Why do we need socket despite of request library in python?
If we wanna socket to connect to other server so what is request library for?

Answer (score 3):

Request is a higher level API for handling HTTP requests (which uses socket internally). There are dozens of other network protocols not covered by it. Of course, you could handle HTTP by using socket directly, but unless you have an **extremely** good reason to do so, you'd just be reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Requests is a Python HTTP library, whereas sockets are used for sending or receiving data on a computer network. HTTP is an **application layer** protocol that specifies how request and replies from client and server should be made. In socket programming, you make connection by specifying destination IP/Port and send your data to remote host.